# invalid destination error in Keycloak SAML integration

Tags: keycloak, saml-2.0, keycloak-services

We are trying to integrate KeyCloak and external IDP using SAML protocol.
After the Keycloak and saml configuration, we tried to test. Keycloak is able to initiate a call to IDP and IDP is returning successful SAML response with requested nameId. But, Keycloak is throwing invalid destination error. Can anyone please help here?

> 19:13:30,964 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-2) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_RESPONSE_ERROR, realmId=XXX, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=XXXX, error=invalid_saml_response, reason=invalid_destination

Comment: Have the same issue. If you turn on trace logs you will probably see that the `requestUri` doesn’t match with the destination from saml xml. I couldn't find a way to make the request uri match, it is in `http` instead of `https` from the saml payload.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoMartinez
I enabled the trace logs. But, still I couldn't see any log related to requestUri. Anyway, I will compare the setup again.

Comment: @FedericoMartinez Thanks for helping out. I am facing exactly the same issue. requestUri is in http mode. But, as per the saml tracer, saml response is having proper url. Do you think this requestUri value is coming as part of HTTP-Post rebinding response?

Comment: If you are using Docker version and have a reverse proxy which also does TLS offloading, let the reverse proxy connect to port 8443 from the docker container (might need to configure the rev proxy for self-signed cert) will solve this problem.